# Objects in Array to Query String?

Tags: javascript, analytics

I'm sure someone here knows how to fix my issue. I got a product array that I want to convert to one long string ([Query String Array](https://wp-mix.com/arrays-uri-requests/)). It's required for a Daisycon pixel.

Result I want for 2 products (example):

`&p[]={pn:example1}{a:12}{iv:example1}{r:30}{qty:1}&p[]={pn:example2}{a:18}{iv:example2}{r:30}{qty:1}`

Now, I got this far. I need to create a line for each item in the array and then paste it together as a string (toString()):

```
var testString = [{"amount":20,"commission_group_code":42,"name":"product1"},{"amount":30,"commission_group_code":30,"name":"product2"}]
var items = []
var newItems = []

for (var i = 0; i < testString.length; i++) {
  items.push(testString[i].name)
}

items.forEach(function(item, index){
  newItems.push(`&p[]={pn:${items}{a:total-product-price}{iv:product-name}{r:total-product-price}{qty:qty}{sku:sku}{cc:compensation-code}`)
})
```

So far, I can't seem to get the result I want. Anyone here that can help me?

Comment: Are you meaning to use template literals? If so, the curly braces are missing the dollar symbol. `\`${value}\``

Comment: @evolutionxbox, that seems to be fine for now. I need a string with each item of the array. So, String #1:```&p[]={pn:${arrrayitem1}{a:20}``` and String #2: ```&p[]={pn:${arrrayitem2}{a:30}```.

These should be glued together into one string; ```&p[]={pn:${arrrayitem1}{a:20}&p[]={pn:${arrrayitem2}{a:30}```

Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Yuhui in the MeasureSlack helped me with the issue. It's best to use the `array.map()` function for this issue. The following code:

```
function() {
  var products = {{daisycon_pixel.transaction_products}}; // Google Tag Manager Variable that contains the array of items
  return products.map(function(product) {
    var productString = '';
    productString += '{pn:' + product.name + '}';
    productString += '{a:' + product.amount + '}';
    productString += '{iv:' + product.name + '}';
    productString += '{r:' + product.amount + '}';
    productString += '{qty:1}'; // Quantity
    // repeat the above for other fields if you have the data, e.g. "sku"
    return productString;
  }).join('&p[]=');
}
```

Hope this helps anyone with similar issues!